# Error in Extending the GuiceApplicationLoader : No implementation for play.Application was bound. while locating play.Application

Tags: java, guice, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.5, guice-3

I am trying to Extend the GuiceApplicationLoader in play java project as shown here in official play documentation. (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection)

I am getting below error:

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for play.Application was bound.
  while locating play.Application

I am using the same code snippet shown in docs.

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;
import play.ApplicationLoader;
import play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder;
import play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader;

public class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {

    @Override
    public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {
    Config extra = ConfigFactory.parseString("a = 1");
    return initialBuilder
        .in(context.environment())
        .loadConfig(extra.withFallback(context.initialConfig()))
        .overrides(overrides(context));
}

}
```

Any suggestion why this is happening ?